# Transpose and make table with small text in corner + big text

Tags: pgfplotstable, csv

Ok, this is what I want to make:

[image]

But I'm struggling with understanding how to make this from an external CSV file. I have this approach because the book will be driven by external files which is maintained by people with no LaTeX knowledge.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{book}

\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableset{col sep=semicolon, string type}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{\currfilebase_information.csv}
Status;Active
Company;NXP
Formats;DIP16,SO16 etc.
Communication;Serial
Other names;bla
Type of HW;bla
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \pgfplotstabletypeset{\currfilebase_information.csv}
    \caption{\currfilebase\ information}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Current output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some more work for implemeting the reading from the file. The advantage is greater flexibility.

In this code the optional argument is the maximum width. If one of the main entries is wider than this, it is scaled down to fit.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname_information.csv}
Status;Active
Company;NXP
Formats;DIP16,SO16 etc.
Communication;Serial
Other names;bla
Type of HW;bla
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\makestatustable}{O{\maxdimen}m}
 {% #1 = optional width, default \maxdimen,
  % #2 = file name
  \jimmy_statustable:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\ior_new:N \g_jimmy_statustable_ior
\tl_new:N \l__jimmy_statustable_body_tl
\seq_new:N \l__jimmy_statustable_temp_seq
\box_new:N \l__jimmy_statustable_data_box

\cs_new_protected:Nn \jimmy_statustable:nn
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__jimmy_statustable_body_tl
  \ior_open:Nn \g_jimmy_statustable_ior { #2 }
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \g_jimmy_statustable_ior
   {
    \__jimmy_statustable_line:nn { #1 } { ##1 }
   }
  \begin{tabular}{|l|}
  \hline
  \tl_use:N \l__jimmy_statustable_body_tl
  \end{tabular}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__jimmy_statustable_line:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__jimmy_statustable_temp_seq { ; } { #2 }
  \__jimmy_statustable_head:x { \seq_item:Nn \l__jimmy_statustable_temp_seq { 1 } }
  \__jimmy_statustable_data:nx { #1 } { \seq_item:Nn \l__jimmy_statustable_temp_seq { 2 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__jimmy_statustable_head:n
 {
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__jimmy_statustable_body_tl { \raisebox{0.5ex}{\tiny #1} \\ }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__jimmy_statustable_head:n { x }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__jimmy_statustable_data:nn
 {
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__jimmy_statustable_body_tl
   {
    \strut
    \hbox_set:Nn \l__jimmy_statustable_data_box {#2}
    \dim_compare:nTF { \box_wd:N \l__jimmy_statustable_data_box < #1 }
     {
      #2
     }
     {
      \resizebox{#1}{!}{#2}
     }
    \\ \hline
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__jimmy_statustable_data:nn { nx }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering\sffamily

\makestatustable[2cm]{\jobname_information.csv}
\caption{\jobname\ information}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering\sffamily

\makestatustable{\jobname_information.csv}
\caption{\jobname\ information}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A version with less space betwee the rules and the data; the width is exactly as stated, unless there's no optional width argument, when the table is at its natural width with no scaling of the entries. It will be at natural width any time the stated width exceeds that of all the entries (no scaling up is done).

I did no scaling to the tiny labels, assuming they'll fit in the stated width.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname_information.csv}
Status;Active
Company;NXP
Formats;DIP16,SO16 etc.
Communication;Serial
Other names;bla
Type of HW;bla
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\makestatustable}{O{\maxdimen}m}
 {% #1 = optional width, default \maxdimen,
  % #2 = file name
  \group_begin:
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt} % reduce the space between rules and entries
  \jimmy_statustable:xn { \dim_eval:n { #1 - 2\tabcolsep - 2\arrayrulewidth } } { #2 }
  \group_end:
 }

\ior_new:N \g_jimmy_statustable_ior
\tl_new:N \l__jimmy_statustable_body_tl
\seq_new:N \l__jimmy_statustable_temp_seq
\box_new:N \l__jimmy_statustable_data_box

\cs_new_protected:Nn \jimmy_statustable:nn
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__jimmy_statustable_body_tl
  \ior_open:Nn \g_jimmy_statustable_ior { #2 }
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \g_jimmy_statustable_ior
   {
    \__jimmy_statustable_line:nn { #1 } { ##1 }
   }
  \begin{tabular}{|l|}
  \hline
  \tl_use:N \l__jimmy_statustable_body_tl
  \end{tabular}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \jimmy_statustable:nn { x }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__jimmy_statustable_line:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__jimmy_statustable_temp_seq { ; } { #2 }
  \__jimmy_statustable_head:x { \seq_item:Nn \l__jimmy_statustable_temp_seq { 1 } }
  \__jimmy_statustable_data:nx { #1 } { \seq_item:Nn \l__jimmy_statustable_temp_seq { 2 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__jimmy_statustable_head:n
 {
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__jimmy_statustable_body_tl { \raisebox{0.5ex}{\tiny #1} \\ }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__jimmy_statustable_head:n { x }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__jimmy_statustable_data:nn
 {
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__jimmy_statustable_body_tl
   {
    \strut
    \hbox_set:Nn \l__jimmy_statustable_data_box {#2}
    \dim_compare:nTF { \box_wd:N \l__jimmy_statustable_data_box < #1 }
     {
      #2
     }
     {
      \resizebox{#1}{!}{#2}
     }
    \\ \hline
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__jimmy_statustable_data:nn { nx }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering\sffamily

\rule{2cm}{1pt}% to show that the width of the following table is exactly as stated

\medskip

\makestatustable[2cm]{\jobname_information.csv}
\caption{\jobname\ information}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering\sffamily

\makestatustable{\jobname_information.csv}
\caption{\jobname\ information}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Further version

Here you *must* specify the width.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname_information.csv}
Status;Active
Company;NXP
Formats;DIP16,SO16 etc.
Communication;Serial
Other names;bla
Type of HW;bla
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\makestatustable}{mm}
 {% #1 = optional width, default \maxdimen,
  % #2 = file name
  \group_begin:
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
  \jimmy_statustable:xn { \dim_eval:n { #1 - 2pt - 2\arrayrulewidth } } { #2 }
  \group_end:
 }

\ior_new:N \g_jimmy_statustable_ior
\tl_new:N \l__jimmy_statustable_body_tl
\seq_new:N \l__jimmy_statustable_temp_seq
\box_new:N \l__jimmy_statustable_data_box

\cs_new_protected:Nn \jimmy_statustable:nn
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__jimmy_statustable_body_tl
  \ior_open:Nn \g_jimmy_statustable_ior { #2 }
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \g_jimmy_statustable_ior
   {
    \__jimmy_statustable_line:nn { #1 } { ##1 }
   }
  \begin{tabular}{|w{l}{#1}|}
  \hline
  \tl_use:N \l__jimmy_statustable_body_tl
  \end{tabular}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \jimmy_statustable:nn { x }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__jimmy_statustable_line:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__jimmy_statustable_temp_seq { ; } { #2 }
  \__jimmy_statustable_head:x { \seq_item:Nn \l__jimmy_statustable_temp_seq { 1 } }
  \__jimmy_statustable_data:nx { #1 } { \seq_item:Nn \l__jimmy_statustable_temp_seq { 2 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__jimmy_statustable_head:n
 {
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__jimmy_statustable_body_tl { \raisebox{0.5ex}{\tiny #1} \\ }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__jimmy_statustable_head:n { x }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__jimmy_statustable_data:nn
 {
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__jimmy_statustable_body_tl
   {
    \strut
    \hbox_set:Nn \l__jimmy_statustable_data_box {#2}
    \dim_compare:nTF { \box_wd:N \l__jimmy_statustable_data_box < #1 }
     {
      #2
     }
     {
      \resizebox{#1}{!}{#2}
     }
    \\ \hline
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__jimmy_statustable_data:nn { nx }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering\sffamily

\rule{2cm}{1pt}% to show that the width of the following table is exactly as stated

\medskip

\makestatustable{2cm}{\jobname_information.csv}
\caption{\jobname\ information}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering\sffamily

\rule{5cm}{1pt}% to show that the width of the following table is exactly as stated

\medskip

\makestatustable{5cm}{\jobname_information.csv}
\caption{\jobname\ information}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, looks really promising! I think it will be the way to go.

Comment: I cannot get this to compile. "Undefined control sequence. l.14 \NewDocumentCommand {\makestatustable}{O{\maxdimen}m}"

Comment: @JimmyWestberg Update your TeX system. In the meantime, add `\usepackage{xparse}`.

Comment: Ah, works good know. But, the hlines aren't lining up with the sides, there's a fix for that too?

Comment: @JimmyWestberg Add `\usepackage{array}`.

Comment: @JimmyWestberg That's what I wrote in the answer, isn't it? Further version added. Please remove the outdated comments.

Comment: You may delete my and your unrelated comments, but, THANK YOU FOR HELPING ME WITH THIS. The book starts to look professional now :)

Answer (score 3):

I would use the `csvsimple` package for processing the csv. You can do arbitrary things with csv files. Something along these lines:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{\currfilebase_information.csv}
Status;Active
Company;NXP
Formats;DIP16,SO16 etc.
Communication;Serial
Other names;bla
Type of HW;bla
\end{filecontents*}

{\sffamily
\csvreader[
    tabular = |@{\,}l|,
    table head = \hline,
    /csv/separator=semicolon,
    late after line = \\\hline
]{\currfilebase_information.csv}{}%
    {{\raisebox{0.3ex}{\tiny\csvcoli}} \\ {\large\,\csvcolii} }
}
\end{document}
```

[image: csvsimple output]

See [its documentation](https://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/csvsimple/csvsimple-l3.pdf).

Comment: Great! I will test next week when I'm back at work.